# YouTube Data API: video update error: the request metadata is invalid

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I get an error when adding title and description translation to some videos.

**Methods I've Tried**

I tested for invalid characters in the title and description I translated and found that there were no errors.
I sent `This is a test video` and `This is a description` for test purposes and it still gave an error.
Although I do not make any changes in the codes, it does not translate in some videos, but in others do.

**The error:**

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> The request metadata is invalid.[400]
> Location[body-other]
> Reason[invalidVideoMetadata]
> Domain[youtube.video]]

**My code:**

```
 VideoLocalization localization = new VideoLocalization();
 localization.Title = "This is a test video";//Title
 localization.Description = "This is a test description";//DESCRIPTION
 video.Localizations.Add("en", localization);//INSERT LANGUAGE

 var my_update_request = youtubeService.Videos.Update(video, "localizations, snippet, status");
 await my_update_request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Please post a wider code context, including the creation and setup of your object `video`.

Comment: @stvar                 
var my_video_response = my_video_request.Execute();
 var video = my_video_response.Items[0];


this way I get video information.
I do not make any changes on this data.

Comment: do a video get and then change what you need in the response and post back the same data.  update requires that all the fields are filled.

Comment: if I remove "status" translate not problem.
var my_video_request = youtubeService.Videos.List("localizations, snippet");
but "localizations, snippet, status"  problem.

I am sending the status data as it is, but there is a problem.

Comment: Status Datas

https://ibb.co/C2K2Gyn

Comment: It's not OK to get `video` from the API (a [Videos resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) object), then to modify it for to pass that back to the API. This is because the API [does not allow setting](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#request-body) certain video properties.

Comment: Thanks, Problem solved.
Problem is "status" update.